# Importing products takes too long on a fresh install of Magento 2 v2.2.4

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, import-products, ubuntu

**Backstory:**

Suddenly, my MySQL database for Magento 2 has failed and been corrupted (This is a development installation and used to enter products data) and I don't have backup of the database except a `.csv` file that I exported from the admin dashboards few days before the disaster hit.

Now I'm left with only this product export of this data and I don't have any other record of my 800+ products.

**What I did:**

I installed a new Server with a fresh install of Magento 2 downloaded directly from the official website and as soon as everything was working, I took an image and a snapshot of the server.

Now everytime I try to import the products and click on 'check data' it just hang for hours with `Please Wait...` message

Then I redo this process after restoring the server to the screenshot with the same result.

**Technical Details:**

```
PHP 7.1
Apache 2
MySQL 5.7
Magento 2.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the traffic to the database.

If there is a lot of traffic to the database then the importing process takes time.

While importing make sure that there is less traffic or no traffic to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't think that's the reason in my case. The server is new (Fresh OS Installation) and the only application on it is Magento 2 (Fresh Installation) and no traffic